# Bruteforce word generator using ascii table and one loop

Tags: java, ascii

How can I create a 'word generator' - in java - that gives me all possible combination of characters within a range of the ascii table and with a certain length or less.

What I did so far is an absolut mess and not a nice solution. It can generate me words in a range of characters (in this example from 48 to 57) but it has a fixed word length of 4.

```
for (int i = 48; i < 58; i++) {
    for (int j = 48; j < 58; j++) {
        for (int k = 48; k < 58; k++) {
            for (int l = 48; l < 58; l++) {
                String bruteword = "" + (char) i + (char) j + (char) k + (char) l;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys understand what I mean. Sorry for mistakes, always hard for me to express such stuff in english.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursion could help here. Suppose you say that `words(min, max, n)` gives you a list of all words `n` long with characters between `min` and `max`. You can implement that by saying that if `n = 0`, the only word is the empty string; otherwise, you have all the words made by appending each possible character to `words(min, max, n - 1)`.

```
List<String> words(char min, char max, int n) {
   List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
   if(n == 0) {
      ret.add("");
      return ret;
   }
   for(String word : words(min, max, n - 1)) {
      for(char c = min; c <= max; ++c) {
         ret.add(word + c);
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

**Edit:**

Iterative solution that also generates all possibilities *less* than the requested length:

```
List<String> words(char min, char max, int n) {
   List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
   ret.add("");
   int start = 0;
   for(int length = 1; length <= n; ++length) {
      int end = ret.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
         for(char c = min; c <= max; ++c) {
            ret.add(ret.get(i) + c);
         }
      }
      start = end;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to save the words, you definitely need recursion, because you are basically using the stack in place of the list:

```
void words(char min, char max, int n) {
   for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
      wordsRecursive("", min, max, i);
   }
}

void wordsRecursive(String base, char min, char max, int n) {
   if(n == 0) {
      System.out.println(base);
   } else {
      for(char c = min; c <= max; ++c) {
         wordsRecursive(base + c, min, max, n - 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: (For that matter, you don't even really need recursion; you could wrap this all up in a loop from 0 to n, starting with the base case list)

Comment: hey thanks alot. You are awesome pal. Is there any possiblity to do it without the ArrayList? I do not need to save those words really, just to check them against another word and then throw them away. But I really do appreaciate the effort!

Comment: Thanks alot. guess I will stick to the solution with the iteration. Thanks for your work! You helped me out alot! Internet cookies for you.